# Select and update subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following document structure in a MongoDB collection:

```
[
    {
        "cells": [
            {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "classes": "head"
            },
            {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 0,
                "classes": "head"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5AWuNaYaB7Sox4mvp"
    },
    {
        "cells": [
            {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 1,
                "classes": "head"
            },
            {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 1,
                "classes": "head"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "qKu3fvdJZ4JedMwMj"
    }
]
```

It's a table I use in a Meteor application.

These are my templates:

```
<template name="table">
    <table>
            {{#each rows}}
                    {{> tableRow}}
            {{/each}}
    </table>
</template>

<template name="tableRow">
    <tr>
            {{#each cells}}
                    {{> tableCell}}
            {{/each}}
    </tr>
</template>

<template name="tableCell">
    <td class="{{classes}}"></td>
</template>
```

and this is my helper:

```
Template.table.helpers({
    rows: function() {
            return Table.find();
    }
});
```

It all renders well. It correctly creates a 2x2 table where all cells have the "head" class, which is a placeholder. When finished, it will have at least 50x50 cells

My problem is: How do I make a mongo query to return one particular cell without returning the whole row? My result should be just

```
{x: 0, y: 0, classes: "head"}
```

I would also like to remove the x and y properties from the document, and use the position in the document to implicitly give x and y, like you lookup a multi-dimensional array with a[y][x].

What's more important, but I guess related to finding the cell object, is updating the cell object. Can you please give an example of how to update the "classes" property of cell (1, 1)?

I'm also open to restructure the whole thing, but I want just one find()-command in the whole thing. The table will be updated often, like several times per second. I tried having a find() for each row, with a different document structure. It worked, and I could query and update each cell with ease, but it took 2 seconds for each query to return on a 50x50 table.

Comment: Briefly speaking, it all depends on the kind of queries you will be using for your data structure. Can you give some more examples describing how you're going to use it?

Comment: I'm making a snake-like game. I need to update the classes of two or three cells every tick, which will be several times per second.

Comment: In "snake", the current state of the game can be encoded in a more compact way, by describing the snake position rather then the whole map. I think it will count, when it comes to efficiency. So if I were you I would create a collection containing "snake" documents, each of them build with a list of "cells" it currently occupies.

Comment: Not sure how to get the reactivity of Meteor through this, but will try.
However, I would still like the original question answered, as it will probably be useful elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store each cell in its own document:

```
{
    "x" : 0,
    "y" : 2,
    "classes" : "head"
}
```

To find one cell, look it up by `x` and `y`.

```
db.cells.find({ "x" : 1, "y" : 3 })
```

To update a cell, find it by `x` and `y` and update it.

```
db.cells.update({ "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }, { "$set" : { "classes" : "tails" } })
```

To find all cells in "two-dimensional array order", sort on `{ "x" : 1, "y" : 1 }`.

db.cells.find({ }, { "_id" : 0, "classes" : 1 }).sort({ "x" : 1, "y" : 1 })

The position in the result set implicitly gives `x` and `y` - you can write a function to calculate `x` and `y` from the position `i` of a cell in the sorted results, based on knowing the dimensions of the table.

I don't think it came up in the question, but it's also easy to find a whole row or column:

```
db.cells.find({ "x" : 0 })
db.cells.find({ "y" : 2 })
```

*Edit on how to find and update just one cell in original document structure*

Use [$elemMatch projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

```
db.cells.find({ "_id" : "5AWuNaYaB7Sox4mvp" }, { "cells" : { "$elemMatch" : { "x" : 0, "y" : 1 } } })

db.cells.update({ "_id" : "5AWuNaYaB7Sox4mvp", "cells" : { "$elemMatch" : { "x" : 0, "y" : 1 } }, { "$set" : { "cells.$.classes" : "tails" } })
```

Comment: This structure appears to work in my case, but it still does not answer the original question. Is that even possible?

Comment: I think I addressed every single part. What else would you like to know?

Comment: If it is possible, using the original document structure, to select and update single cells in a document. I don't really need it anymore, but nice to know for the future.